# Display submitted form data after redirecting to the same page

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, session-cookies

How to redirect after the submit button to the same page? Note: in form i have two button, I want show user only one link, when the user click on it he must be redirected to another link and this link will redirect him to do same page form but this time showing the button for submit.

I'm not familiar with PHP (session) but at least I have an idea how it will work. This is the idea:

```
        <form method="get" action="index.php">
    <br>

    <h2> ID : <input name="id" placeholder="your Id"/ size="45"/></h2><br>

    </br>

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['link'])) {

    ?>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="==>Submite<==" id="submit" />
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    <a href="id.php">Click Here Before Submit </a>
    <?php } 

    ?>
    </form> 
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['link'])){

session_start(); 
{$_SESSION['link'] = $_GET['link'];}
header('location: redirection.php'); 
}
?>
```

Page redirection.php should test in index.php if the user clicked on the link if yes so user will be auto redirected to index.php with button submit `header("Location: index.php")`.

exemple website : old-skys.net/cc

Answer (score -1):

```
<h2> ID : <input name="id" placeholder="your Id"/ size="45"/></h2><br>

</br>

<?php if ($_GET['action']=='step2') {

?>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="==>Submite<==" id="submit" />
<?php
} else {
?>
<a href="id.php?action=step2">Click Here Before Submit </a>
<?php } 

?>
```

Please test it

Comment: Hello, please add some explanation as to what you changed and why this code might work. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: you can click <a href="id.php?action=step2">Click Here Before Submit </a> when it check  $_GET['action']=='step2' it can show.

Comment: Please edit your answer, do not post the explanation in the comments. It will be much easier to read if they are in your answer.

Comment: thank you guys for answer, but i want something like this : http://www.old-skys.net/cc/ 
when you click :  "Click Here Before Submit" you are auto redirected to the same page with same form but with bouton submite.